# How A complex submanifold satisfies the Newlander-Nirenberg integrability criterion.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm reading Voisin's book Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry.

For the definition of complex submanifold, she said:
A complex submanifold $N$ of a complex manifold $M$ is a differentiable submanifold whose tangent space at each point is stable under the almost complex structure $I_M$ of $M$.

Then she claimed that on the submanifold $N$ with the induced almost complex structure $I_N$, $(N,I_N)$ is **integrable**, i.e. satisfies the Newlander-Nirenberg integrability criterion.

Recall that for a manifold $X$ with an almost complex structure $I$ on its tangent space $T_X$, we say $(X,I)$ satisfies the Newlander-Nirenberg condition if
$$[T_X^{0,1},T_X^{0,1}]\subset T_X^{0,1}$$.

Back to the question, it is clear that $T_N^{0,1}\subset T_M^{0,1}$ since the almost complex structure $I_N$ on $N$ comes from the complex structure $I_M$on $ M$ and, by defintion (of a complex submanifold) , $T_N$ is stable under $I_M$.

Since $M$ is a complex manifold, by Newlander-Nirenberg Thm, $(M,I_M)$ satifies Newlander-Nirenberg condition.

But I don't think it is obvious that $(N,I_N)$ also satisfies the Newlander-Nirenberg condition.

Answer (score 3):

Choose local holomorphic coordinates $(z^1,\dots,z^n)$ on $M$ adapted to $N$ — i.e., so that $N$ is given by $z^{k+1}=\dots=z^n=0$.